# Word press plugin issues

Tags: php, wordpress

The error reads:

Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /home/u111917130/domains/earthaventures.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/app/Common/Traits/Helpers/WpContext.php on line 354

Line 354 reads: $postContent          = str_replace( ']]>', ']]>', $postContent );

I was told to just update the plugins and I did that or to downgrade my php but I don't want to do that I would rather just update the code but I am not entirely sure what to change without affecting the rest of my code because I don't know what represents ']]>' and what represents ']]&gt'

Could someone assist with what I could write to change the code like a conditional statement of some sort. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migration to PHP 8.1 - how to fix Deprecated Passing null to parameter error - rename build in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71707325/migration-to-php-8-1-how-to-fix-deprecated-passing-null-to-parameter-error-r)

Comment: To address your specific case the two solutions here would work: https://3v4l.org/dCIvo

Comment: I tracked that specific line down in the [plugin's source](https://github.com/awesomemotive/all-in-one-seo-pack/blob/a2af39226741bfa9e4f6ebf30226381dc72998f0/app/Common/Traits/Helpers/WpContext.php#L354C58-L354C70) and I'd be surprised if they have any interest in addressing it because I don't think they'd expect it to ever be null. That means that this will be broken again when the plugin updates next time, which I think happens fairly often.