# Strange result in loop when use special chars

Tags: php, loops, character-encoding

I have strange problem when special chars in loop when add br and use specal chars, if don´t use words with special chars no have problems but when use special chars and use br for show one under other show strange chars

**For example if don´t use br :**

```
$text="ála";

for($d=0;$d<strlen($text);$d++)
{

echo $text[$d];
    
}
```

**Result:** ála

**If use br show strange chars**

```
$text="ála";

for($d=0;$d<strlen($text);$d++)
{

echo $text[$d];
print "<br>";
    
}
```

**Result :** �
�
l
a

I don´t know how fix it´s and don´t underetand why happend this issue, howewer here can explain what happend, regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because an accented e is part of UTF-8, which are considered "multi-byte" characters. It outputs incorrectly because you're actually splitting the character down the middle and putting `<br>` in-between. Because you are splitting on the bytes of the string, and not the characters, the computer does not understand that there is an accented e anymore.

If you are using PHP 7.4, you can use the `mb_str_split` function instead. You need to have the `mbstring` extension enabled.

If you don't have that enabled, this answer can help you do it without: [What is the best way to split a string into an array of Unicode characters in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396434/what-is-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-unicode-characters-in-ph/54490847#54490847)